# Conflicting method parameters

Tags: java, arrays, class, parameters, int

This is a portion of the client provided by my prof and I'm not allowed to make changes to it.

```
public static void print (String title, int [] anArray) {
    System.out.print(title + ": ");
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(anArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
System.out.println("\nTesting constructor");
ScoreList list1 = new ScoreList(13);

System.out.println("\nTesting accessor (getter)");
int[] list1_array = list1.getScores();

System.out.println("\nTesting toString");
System.out.print("list1:        " + list1);

System.out.println("\nTesting our print method");
print("list1's array", list1_array);

ScoreList list2 = new ScoreList(list1_array);

System.out.println("\nTesting list1 and list2");
System.out.println("list1:      " + list1);
System.out.println("list2:      " + list2);

System.out.println("\nTesting equals");
System.out.println("It is " + list1.equals(list2)
                            + " that list1 is equal to list2");

if (!list1.equals(list2)) {
    System.out.println("Error. The equals method does not work correctly");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

This is a portion of my code that I wrote that will be tested by this client:

```
int [] scores;

public ScoreList(int size) {
    if (size >= 1) {
        this.scores = new int [size];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.scores.length; i++) {               
            this.scores[i] = random(100);
        }
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("Length of array must be greater than or equal to 1.");
    }
}

public ScoreList(int [] size) {
    if (size.length >= 1) {
        this.scores = new int [size.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.scores.length; i++) {
            this.scores[i] = random(100);
        }
    } 
}

private int random(int randomAmount) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(randomAmount);
    return randomNumber;
}

public int [] getScores() {
    int [] temp = new int [scores.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = this.scores[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

The error here is that list1 and list2 will never be equal because I have 2 constructors, one that accepts int as a parameter and one that accepts int []. They both call random() simultaneously to provide the elements for list1 and list2. To make them equal, I think there should only be one constructor, so random() will only be called once. However, the parameters conflict. You see, according to the client, list1's parameter is 13, an int; list2's parameter is an int[].

This is the instruction I got from my prof on how to create the constructor for this class:

> A constructor with just one parameter, the size of this object’s scores array, which must
>   be ≥ 1. It creates an array of the supplied size and the then fills that array with random
>   integers between 0 and 100, inclusive.

Comment: Shoudn't `public ScoreList(int [] size)` just initialize list with given array and not generate new array? Definition of constructor in the end talks only about `ScoreList(int size)` constructor.

Comment: Ah. I think I get what you mean. So, this.scores[i] = size[i]? I'm not sure if that's the right way to code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want, but I think you just create the function creating new array from the other.

The second constructor could be like below.

```
public ScoreList(int[] array) {
    // If you have to check array size, do it in here.
    this.scores = new int[array.length];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        this.scores[i] = array[i];
    } 
}
```

or If there should be only one constructor, please make it as a function.

Comment: Yes. It's already midnight here and I can't think straight, so I just realized that the 2nd constructor should just get a copy of the array that's already initialized and not create a new one. Thank you.